# Can Cross Account Access EC2 Role be Created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

This can be divided in 3 Parts:

Q1) For a Piece of Code Running on EC2 Instance Ec2 Role Super Seeds AWS Config Credentials , because code could not access s3 bucket and awsr rkognition collections , but when I used AWS Configure on instance and added access and secret key I could access resources via aws cli.
But when I ran it through my code it gave an error which on debugged showed aws role arn stating access denied.

Q2) I Deployed an Application On Account *1111111* With AWS Codestar 
It Requires following Resources:
1) AWS S3 
2) AWS Rekognition

Now the Scenario is that the bucket and Collection of AWS Rekognition are on Different AWS Account *2222222*.

AWS Code Star Automatically Assigns A role to EC2 Instance and if I Remove it codestar breaks so role that has that accounts code deploy must be kept.

What can done in this scenario i know [S3 Bucket can be given cross account access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) but what about Rekognition

Can Some One Tell Me Exactly What IAM Settings needs to applied on what accounts if someone wants to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a role on the destination AWS account (222222?) that allows access to the resource by allocating a "trusted entity" using the ARN of the source account (111111). In particular this should be the ARN of the connecting service, in your case the ARN of the EC2 instance on account (111111). For further information, see:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: You mean to see I created a role in account 222 with trustred ARN of EC2 instance of account 1 , I can do that from link to S3 but what about AWS Recognition ? If you look at question I mention that it can be done to S3 I am concerned about AWS Recognition

Comment: oh, i read the question as "Can Cross Account Access EC2 Role be Created?" for which the answer is, yes.